# Rsync only two dictionaries

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I want to work localy on some programm, which I want to test and run on a remote server. The only files I am editing are the `*.hpp` and `*.cpp` in the `src` and the `include` directory.

For that I tried this `rsync` command, to only upload the necessarry source files:

`rsync --dry-run -av --exclude '*' --include 'src/*.cpp' --include 'include/*.hpp' Programm/ user@remote:/home/user/Programm`

But for some reason no files are commited to the server after some local changes.

Any hints appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to put `exclude` statement in the end? Thus include include exclude src dst

Comment: Makes no difference if at the end or beginning. If I understood it properly the includes are only exceptions to the excludes. So I thought all exludes are applied together, and then the includes are added as exceptions, right? Anyway, empirically it makes no difference in my case... But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you were using some form of source control, you wouldn't need `rsync`.

Comment: You must include all the parent directories: thus add `--include 'include/'  --include 'src/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's excerpt from the `rsync` man page, which tackles your exact problem.

> Note that, when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by
>   -a), every subdir component of every path is visited left to right, with each directory having a chance for exclusion before its content.
>   In this way include/exclude patterns are applied recursively to the
>   pathname of each node in the filesystem's tree (those inside the
>   transfer). The exclude patterns short-circuit the directory traversal
>   stage as rsync finds the files to send.
>
> For instance, to include "/foo/bar/baz", the directories "/foo" and
>   "/foo/bar" must not be excluded. Excluding one of those parent
>   directories prevents the examination of its content, cutting off
>   rsync's recursion into those paths and rendering the include for
>   "/foo/bar/baz" ineffectual (since rsync can't match something it never
>   sees in the cut-off section of the directory hierarchy).
>
> The concept path exclusion is particularly important when using a
>   trailing '*' rule. For instance, this won't work:
>
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
>   + /file-is-included
>   - *
>
> This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the '*' rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the "some" or
>   "some/path" directories. One solution is to ask for all directories in
>   the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it
>   somewhere before the "- *" rule), and perhaps use the
>   --prune-empty-dirs option. Another solution is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited. For instance,
>   this set of rules works fine:
>
> + /some/
>   + /some/path/
>   + /some/path/this-file-is-found
>   + /file-also-included
>   - *